# Cassandra configuration config by cqlsh

Tags: cassandra, cql, cassandra-3.0, cqlsh

Cassandra version: `3.9`, CQLSH version: `5.0.1`

Can I query Cassandra configuration (`cassandra.yaml`) using `cqlsh`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not possible in your version.  It's possible only starting with Cassandra 4.0 that has so-called virtual tables, and there is a special table for configurations: `system_views.settings`:

```
cqlsh:test> select * from system_views.settings ;
 name                                            | value
-------------------------------------------------+-------
     transparent_data_encryption_options_enabled | false
   transparent_data_encryption_options_iv_length |    16
                                   trickle_fsync | false
                    trickle_fsync_interval_in_kb | 10240
                  truncate_request_timeout_in_ms | 60000
....
```

You can find more information on the virtual tables in the [following blog post from TLP](https://thelastpickle.com/blog/2019/03/08/virtual-tables-in-cassandra-4_0.html).

In the meantime, you can access configuration parameters via JMX.